# Messing with Character Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, pointers

Can someone advise why the loop in the main dies after the fifth iteration never completing
    it's intended goal of reducing the character array down to 1 final element? I've gotten it this 
    far and am completely consumed as their should be 11 iterations as returned by the call

```
size_t strlen( char const *str )
{
    int length = 0;
    while (*str++ !='\0')
    {
        length += 1;
    }
    return length;
}


void abracadabra( char *word )
{
    int i, c;
    int len = strlen(word)-1;
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        putchar(*word);
        putchar(' ');
        *(word++);

    }
}


int main()
{
    char word[250];
    int i, j;

    printf ("enter your word:\n");
    scanf ("%[^\n]s", &word);

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(word)-1; i++)
    {
        abracadabra(word);
        putchar('\0');
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            putchar('\0'); 
        }
        word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0'; 
    }
    word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0'; 
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As well as what's in the accepted answer there are other mistakes; several places you do `strlen(word) - 1` which fails when `strlen(word)` was 0; and `putchar('\0')` is a mistake. `'\0'` is a non-printable character, it's used internally for marking the end of a string but you should not try and write it to a stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you execute the outer for loop in main the size of the string decreases by 1.  The counter i is also increasing by 1 each time.  This causes you to run the loop half of the times that you intend to.

```
int size = strlen(word);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    \\same inner code
}
```

Subbing the above code for the outer for loop in main resolves the issue.

Comment: Actually this code is the more accurate for what assignment was. A sort of word triangle. Really can't thank everyone enough.

Answer (score 0):

The is mistake in using the variable `i and strlen` in `for` loop. `i` is keep increasing and word length is decreasing. So in the mid, loop is terminated due to i>strlen (word)

```
int main()
{
    char word[250];
    int i, j;

    printf ("enter your word:\n");
    scanf ("%[^\n]s", &word);

   // for (i = 0; i <= strlen(word)-1; i++)
   while ( strlen(word) )
    {
        abracadabra(word);
        putchar('\0');
        printf("\n");           
        word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0'; 
    }

    word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0'; 
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. While loop definitely simplified the code and that's always good. 'm a noob so i tend to overcomplicate my functions. Much appreciated